# plugins loader if one server is down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know to give a title with it but i just want to explain it through my example.

I have a problem like this now. I get all my third party libraries from the `cdn` site like google..

Example:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

My problem is if ever there is an Internet failure my site will be affected because i can't get my third party libraries..

I think that its better for me to have an alternative source which is `local` sources..

But how to switch to `local` sources (like `http://localhost:123/jquery/`) when ever there is downtime in my Internet so that my site will not be affected even if there is an Internet downtime.

The reason I want to use the `cdn` like google because of bandwidth issues...

Please give me an idea..

Actually I read about `Yepnope.js` but its not clear to me if it is the solution to my problem. Is anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a copy of the library on your computer of course and you can also put one on your server in case the CDN goes down (unlikely with Google!).

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path-to-your-local-copy/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

Comment: yes im still reading about yepnope and hopefully it is the answer to my problem but just a hint for me can you give me an idea how to use yepnope?

Comment: `yepnope([{
    load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',
    complete: function() {
     window.jQuery || yepnope('/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');
    }
}, {
    load: '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    complete: function() {
    window.jQuery.fn.modal || yepnope('/js/bootstrap-3.0.3.min.js');
    }
}]);`

Comment: where did you get `window.jQuery.fn.modal` coz i have many libraries how will i make a condition to it if it fall

Comment: You'll have to do some research on how plugins are loaded in yepnope. jQuery.fn.modal is called  in bootstrap modal, which triggers yepnope to load the plugin. More than I can discuss in a comment